# How to disable past dates in Android date picker?

Tags: android

How can I disable past dates in my Android date picker?

Here's the code that produces my DatePicker:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        // set date picker as current date
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month,
                day);
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        year = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth+1;
        day = selectedDay;

        startdate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day).append("-")
                .append(getMonth(month + 1)).append("-").append(year)
                .append(" "));
    }
};
```

Comment: DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), date, myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
                datePickerDialog.show();

Comment: Thanks worked, by adding 'datePicker.minDate = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000'

Answer (score 265, accepted):

You can do

```
datePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```

which sets today's date as minimum date and all the past dates are disabled.

`datePicker` is an object of `DatePicker` if you are using an object of `DatePickerDialog` you can do

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```

**Note: `setMinDate` was introduced in API 11**

Comment: Thanks for the response.. Where should I have to put this line ?

Comment: Where you create your `DatePicker` or `DatePickerDialog` object

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But when I used the above solution it gave me crash in my application. So I changed the "System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000" to "System.currentTimeMillis() - 10000" and my application worked perfectly. Can you please lemme know why I am getting crash on subtracting 1000 but not on 10000

Comment: the previous dates are disabled but they can be selected :(

Comment: how to set custom date as minimum date?

Suppose I've two date pickers, one is start date and another in end date. How limit end date from start date?

Comment: this one also works fine for me          **datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis())**
then what is the difference between **setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis()) and setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis()-1000)**

Comment: May I know the reason of having `-1000`?

Comment: Why -1000 ?????

Comment: It basically means the min date is 1 second ago.

Answer (score 20):

This method will work properly.

```html
//Get yesterday's date
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);

//Set yesterday time milliseconds as date pickers minimum date
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, myDateListener, year, month, day);
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
datePickerDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 13):

With the Material Components Library just use the **`MaterialDatePicker`** and build your own `DateValidator` or you can just use the **`DateValidatorPointForward`** provided by the library.

Something like:

```
MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Long> builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();

CalendarConstraints.DateValidator dateValidator = DateValidatorPointForward.now();
//if you need a custom date just use
//CalendarConstraints.DateValidator dateValidator = DateValidatorPointForward.from(yourDate);
constraintsBuilder.setValidator(dateValidator);
builder.setCalendarConstraints(constraintsBuilder.build());

MaterialDatePicker<Long> picker = builder.build();
picker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), picker.toString());
```

[image]

Comment: I like the "here's some code, go figure it out" approach material.io took documenting this. https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/catalog/java/io/material/catalog/datepicker/DatePickerMainDemoFragment.java

Answer (score 8):

This is how I do it:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
OnDateSetListener ondateSet;
Calendar c;
int year = 0, month = 0, day = 0;

public DatePickerFragment() {
}

public void setCallBack(OnDateSetListener ondate) {
    ondateSet = ondate;
}

public static DatePickerFragment newInstance(Bundle bundle) {
    DatePickerFragment myFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    myFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return myFragment;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
//if else for null arguments
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        year = getArguments().getInt("year");
        month = getArguments().getInt("month");
        day = getArguments().getInt("day");
        c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(year, month, day);

    } else {
        c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        Log.d("else", "else");
    }


    DatePickerDialog picker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
            ondateSet, year, month, day);
    picker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTime().getTime());
    Log.d("picker timestamp", c.getTime().getTime() + "");
    return picker;
}
}
```

This is how you instantiate the picker:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        bundle.putInt("year", c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        bundle.putInt("month", c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        bundle.putInt("day", c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        DatePickerFragment fragment = DatePickerFragment
                .newInstance(bundle);
        fragment.setCallBack(dateSet);
        fragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
```

This is my implementation feel free to change it. Note that this code sets mindate as currnet date by default. Also the newInstance is important.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using DatePicker

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Output]

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        String _year = String.valueOf(year);
        String _month = (month+1) < 10 ? "0" + (month+1) : String.valueOf(month+1);
        String _date = dayOfMonth < 10 ? "0" + dayOfMonth : String.valueOf(dayOfMonth);
        String _pickedDate = year + "-" + _month + "-" + _date;
        Log.e("PickedDate: ", "Date: " + _pickedDate); //2019-02-12
    }
}, c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 4):

**Kotlin**

Directly to the Date Picker:

```
datePicker.minDate = System.currentTimeMillis()
```

If you are using an object of DatePickerDialog:

```
datePickerDialog.datePicker.minDate = System.currentTimeMillis()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this line into your code...

```
private Calendar cal;
private int day;
private int month;
private int year;

static final int DATE_PICKER_ID = 1111; 
TextView textView;

    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            showDialog(DATE_PICKER_ID);

        }
    });

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DATE_PICKER_ID:
            // create a new DatePickerDialog with values you want to show

            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month, day);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 0); // Add 0 days to Calendar
            Date newDate = calendar.getTime();
            datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(newDate.getTime()-(newDate.getTime()%(24*60*60*1000)));
            return datePickerDialog;
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    // the callback received when the user "sets" the Date in the
    // DatePickerDialog
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

        textViewTime.setText(selectedDay + "/" + (selectedMonth + 1) + "/" + selectedYear);
    }
};
```

Comment: And what for `calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 0);` and a `Calendar calendar` itself if it is not used? Date newDate = new Date(); is enough.

Answer (score 3):

You can use DatePicker#setMinDate() function to set a minimum date.

```
 datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I am using [MaterialDatePicker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker) Library and its too simple to set minimum date on it.

```
DatePickerDialog mDatePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(listener,
                mTime.year, mTime.month, mTime.monthDay);
mDatePickerDialog.setYearRange(2016, 2036);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
mDatePickerDialog.setMinDate(c);
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Here is how i solved it.

> Step 1: Declare click listener for opening the date picker.

```
dateTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         showDateTimePicker();
     }
 });
```

> Step 2: Declare a listener which listens for Date change.

```
    public void showDateTimePicker(){
     final Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
     date = Calendar.getInstance();
     DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new 
     DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int 
     monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
     date.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    //use this date as per your requirement
     }
 };
}
```

> Step 3: Now we need to declare a date picker dialog too inside the above showDateTimePicker() method. We will also be limiting the access to past dates in this step.

```
          public void showDateTimePicker(){
             final Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
             date = Calendar.getInstance();

            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new 
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
             @Override
             public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int 
             monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
             date.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

            //use this date as per your requirement
             }
         };
          DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new  
          DatePickerDialog(**Your Activity Name.this**, dateSetListener, 
          currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), 
          currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH),   
          currentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        // Limiting access to past dates in the step below:
 datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
         datePickerDialog.show();
        }
```

> This is all that you need to do. Here is the final code that you may want to look:

```
    private Date date;

dateTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             showDateTimePicker();
         }
     });



public void showDateTimePicker(){
 final Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
date = Calendar.getInstance();

 DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
         date.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

    //use this date as per your requirement
     }
 };
 DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new  DatePickerDialog(**Your Activity Name.this**, dateSetListener, currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH),   currentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
 datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
 datePickerDialog.show();
}
```

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @VishalChhodwani Thanks for the input. Have made some edits. :)

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what you want to disable if you want to set to minimum date to be up to a couple of days then the best approach is to use LocalDateTime like this:

```
        val ldt: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(30)
        val zone: ZoneId = ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin")

        val zoneOffSet: ZoneOffset = zone.rules.getOffset(ldt)
        dpd.datePicker.minDate = ldt.toInstant(zoneOffSet).toEpochMilli()
        dpd.datePicker.maxDate = System.currentTimeMillis()
        dpd.show()
```

You set the new local date-time to be up to **minus 30 days from now** and after that, you set in which time zone it needs to be for my example I am using "Europe/Berlin" time, you attach it to 
**dpd.datePicker.minDate = ldt.toInstant(zoneOffSet).toEpochMilli()** 
set to epochMilli and that's it

Comment: Very fine answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If this is your date picker  (code from my own existing project)

```
   <DatePicker
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="17dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/outlinedTextField"
                android:datePickerMode="calendar"/>
```

Reference the DatePicker as follows :

```
 private DatePicker date;
```

Inside appropriate method initialize it depending on whether fragment or activity whatever

```
  date = view.findViewById(R.id.date);
```

Before you select the data or submit make sure you disable the past date (date before today or depending on your need ) like

```
     // disable date before today
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
    long now = today.getTimeInMillis();
    date.setMinDate(now);
```

Now all the past dates will be disabled meaning they will not be selectable. That should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an object of `DatePickerDialog

```
datePicker.setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```

This will disable past dates.

Answer (score 0):

For me, to disable year, month, and the days, I used below code

```
datePickerDialog.minDate = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
            set(
                minYear,
                minMonth,
                minMonth,
                currentDate.hours,
                currentDate.minutes + 1
            )
        }
```