# how to fix this ? i can't disable my past date using datepicker dialog

Tags: android

I want to disable past dates in datepicker.

```
new DatePickerDialog(this,listener,calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
DatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
DatePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable past dates in Android date picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23762231/how-to-disable-past-dates-in-android-date-picker)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);

    new DatePickerDialog(this,listener,calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    DatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(calendar1.getTimeInMillis());
    DatePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
  
  @Override
  public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, arg1);
   calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, arg2);
   calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, arg3);
   txtDate.setText(format.format(calendar.getTime()));
  } 
 };

Answer (score 0):

you can just pass the setMaxDate() for the DatePickerDailog,

```
DatePickerDialog dateDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), myDateListener, year, 
 month, day);
dateDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

Or you can also do this,

```
dateDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
```