# How to disable all previous dates from selected date in datepicker in android

Tags: android, datepicker

I want to disable all previous dates in one date picker while i select a date in another date picker. **Please don't put answer to disable all previous dates from current date**. *I want from selected date, not from current date.*

Such as i selected 22Dec on first date picker, Now in second date picker, all previous dates from 22Dec should be disable.

Comment: Please elaborate little more and show how you have tried to achieve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable past dates in Android date picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23762231/how-to-disable-past-dates-in-android-date-picker)

Comment: @LS_ no, please read once to my question carefully.

Comment: @BhunnuBaba You just need to adapt the code, but that's the solution. Implement `onDateSet` and use `datePicker.setMinDate()` to disable dates based on user's selection.

Comment: may you put an example for getting date in onDateSet method and put it in seMinDate method for more clearance ? Thanks for your previous reply.